# Excel VBA Indirect workaround

Tags: excel, vba, excel-indirect

**UPDATE**

see original question below.

Code is now:

Function Getvalue(CellRange As String) As Variant

```
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim sheet As String
Dim str As String 
set rng = Range(Cell Range)

    yr = Format(CStr(Now), "yy")
monthn = Format(CStr(Now), "mmmm")

path = "C:\Folder\Subfolder\"
file = "File-" & monthn & ", FY''" & yr & ".xls"
sheet = "Sheet1"
rng = Range(CellRange)

str = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & rng.Address( , ,xlR1C1)
```

GetValue = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)
End Function

```
Sub Routine()
Call GetValue("A1")
End Sub
```

When I use the subroutine in VBA and go through the function with F8, with "GetValue" being watched, The value of GetValue returns what I want. It pulls the data from the closed workbook. However when I put =GetValue("A1") into a cell on my worksheet, it returns #VALUE!

---

old:

I have a worksheet that references data from one workbook in multiple columns. My issue is that the workbook is updated and renamed every month (and every year). I could go through and change the link every month but I feel like there should be an automated way to do it.

Let's say the filename is (File-August, FY''20) so every month/year I would be changing the month/year in the filename.

I don't want to use the indirect function as I would like to be able to keep the reference workbook closed.

But basically I want an alternative to:

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\Folder\Subfolder\[File-" & TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm") & ", FY''" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yy") & ".xls]Sheet1'!" & A1)
```

(Full path is 'C:\Folder\Subfolder[File-August, FY''20.xls]Sheet1'!A1)

Month, year, and cell are dynamic.

I am a beginner with VBA, so I've pieced together some code from research, but I know there are probably many things wrong with it. I tried to make it so that I could use a UDF and just call the cell, but I don't know if that is even possible.

```vb
Function Getvalue(CellRange As String) As Variant

    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim sheet As String
    Dim str As String 
    Dim rng As Range
    
        yr = Format(CStr(Now), "yy")
    monthn = Format(CStr(Now), "mmmm")
    
    path = "C:\Folder\Subfolder\"
    file = "File-" & monthn & ", FY''" & yr & ".xls"
    sheet = "Sheet1"
    rng = Range(CellRange)
    
    str = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & rng
    
  Result = ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)
    
End Function
```

This returns `#VALUE` when entered.

thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you calling this? What is the argument you are passing?

Comment: Great question, I guess the answer is I don't think I am? maybe that's what I'm missing. How exactly would I do that?

Comment: What are you typing in a cell? Something like `=Getvalue("A1")`?

Comment: yes, also tried GetValue(A1) without quotation marks and both returned #VALUE

Comment: `& rng` might need to be `& rng.Address`.

Comment: still getting #VALUE!

Comment: Try debugging from the VB Editor by creating a subroutine that calls this function and stepping through with F8.

Comment: but I only changed the third to last line(str="...) . should I replace it in all other instances?

Comment: wrote the subroutine as  

 sub Routine()  ;
Call GetValue("A1")  ;
end sub  ;  

Just want to make sure thats right.

then I went though it with F8:
When it gets to line "rng = Range(CellRange)"
I get Run-time error '91': Object variable or With clock variable not set"

Comment: range variable need to be written with `Set rng = Range(CellRange)` unless (you can look at local variable pannel) but its most likely store as variant. Add `Option Explicit` on top of your code to spot any other mistake like this

Comment: @PatatesPilées - good catch on the missing `Set`, but note that OP does have `Dim rng as Range` already. Nice to see you contributing!

Comment: I tried deleting the `Dim rng as Range` line and adding "set" to the `rng=Range(CellRange)` line. It lets me go through the whole code with F8 now, but then I get "Run-time error '1004': There's an error in the formula you entered. make sure[...]"

Comment: I think the issue now is with the second to last line `Result=ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)`

Comment: I think Im getting closer.
I added "xlR1C1" to the Address and "Application" to the last line so that it looks like this. Based on some googling about using the ExecuteExcelMacro function.........

`str = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & rng.Address(, , xlR1C1)  
  result = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)`

Now when I go though with F8 and a watch on "result", the value is able to pull the cell from the other workbook and displays what I want. BUT when I use the GetValue function in my sheet, I'm still getting #VALUE!

Comment: `Getvalue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(str)`  Assigning a value to `Result` doesn't return a value from your functon.

Comment: I actually did correct that, but it still returns #Value. Everything seems to run correctly but the function isnt working in the sheet

Comment: I added the updated code to the original question for clarification

Comment: Seems like `ExecuteExcel4Macro` is not permitted in a UDF   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521245/a-function-within-a-function-in-vba for discussion