# What is the difference between running an Excel VBA function from the developer’s IDE (F5) and calling a function (=) from the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Consider this code:

```
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler    
    Application.Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"
    HelloWorld = "Success"    
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    HelloWorld = Err.Description
End Function
```

When I run this within the developer's IDE with F5/F8 it will put "Hello World" in cell A1 as desired. But when I run this in the spreadsheet with "=HelloWorld()" I get the error "Application-defined or object-defined error".

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: UDF can't directly change other cells https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: You may execute actions restricted in UDF by scheduling, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23232311/2165759)

Comment: Thanks Slai for the reference. I didn’t realize this limitation.

Comment: @SamG. Not a limitation as much as way to help prevent paradoxical circular references and such.  Same reason you can't have a formula that changes itself.