# Unable to access macro Function value in excel cell when used inside formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having a problem where the VBA macro function I have written seem to show correct answer when I try to run it in Immediate Window. But when I access it in a cell using formula bar, it shows #VALUE! error. I don't understand why.

This is the function:-

```
Function RetrieveBufferDays(cellValue As String) As Long
    Dim bufferDays As Long
    Dim Combined As String
    Dim BufferDayFile As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim wbCombined As Workbook
    Dim wsTest As Worksheet
    Dim PartNumberArray() As Variant
    
    Dim wbBufferDay As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim AllBufferDays() As Variant
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    
    bufferDays = 0
    Combined = "D:\Project\Combined.xlsx"
    BufferDayFile = "D:\Project\BufferDays.xlsx"
    
    
    
    ' Step 1:- Retrieve PartNumbers from Combined.xlsx file
    Set wbCombined = Workbooks.Open(Combined, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsTest = wbCombined.Sheets("Test")
    
    lastRow = wsTest.Cells(wsTest.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ReDim PartNumberArray(1 To 1) ' Initialize array
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If wsTest.Cells(i, "E").Value = cellValue Then
            ' Found a match, add Column H value to the array
            PartNumberArray(UBound(PartNumberArray)) = wsTest.Cells(i, "H").Value
            ReDim Preserve PartNumberArray(1 To UBound(PartNumberArray) + 1) ' Resize array for the next value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Remove the last empty element in the array
    ReDim Preserve PartNumberArray(1 To UBound(PartNumberArray) - 1)
    
    ' Close the workbook
    wbCombined.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
        
    
    ' Step 2:- Retrieve BufferDays from BufferDays.xlsx file
    Set wbBufferDay = Workbooks.Open(BufferDayFile)
    Set wsSheet = wbBufferDay.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    lastRow = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ReDim AllBufferDays(1 To 1) ' Initialize array
    
    ' Loop through each value in PartNumberArray
    For i = LBound(PartNumberArray) To UBound(PartNumberArray)
        
        Dim searchValue As Variant
        searchValue = PartNumberArray(i)
    
        For j = 1 To lastRow
            If wsSheet.Cells(j, "A").Value = searchValue Then
                ' Found a match, add Column B value to the array
                AllBufferDays(UBound(AllBufferDays)) = wsSheet.Cells(j, "B").Value
                ReDim Preserve AllBufferDays(1 To UBound(AllBufferDays) + 1) ' Resize array for the next value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Close the BufferDayFile workbook
    wbBufferDay.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
    
    
    ' Step 3:- Find Max of AllBufferDays
    bufferDays = WorksheetFunction.Max(AllBufferDays)
        
    
    
    RetrieveBufferDays = bufferDays
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    
End Function
```

This is how I am trying to access its value in formula bar:-

```
=RetrieveBufferDays(B3)
```

The reason I am writing a function instead of directly writing and applying it as a formula is because I already have a very big formula from which RetrieveBufferDays(B3) is to be subtracted. Along with this Excel does not have inbuilt lookup function that returns multiple rows for duplicate matches making formula for RetrieveBufferDays long as well.

When I try to implement the full formula (put it in one row, then drag it to next 1000 rows) it works for few rows but eventually starts showing "***Formulas cannot be calculated. There isn't enough memory or system resources to calculate formulas***" and I don't want to (if possible) manually adjust row variables in the formula for each of 1000 rows.

Therefore, I would request your help in either getting the function show value in excel cells or  implement the long formula for all 1000 rows without getting the resource error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226657/excel-vba-load-worksheet-in-function/23232311. VBA UDFs are limited in what they can do, including `Workbooks.Open`.

Comment: The function appears to be opening and closing 2 workbooks. So if you drag this to 1,000 cells, you are opening and closing the same 2 workbooks 1,000 times, and every time you recalculate. Seems like this would be better done as a Sub that opens the workbooks once, then loops through all 100 rows. Or through Power Query, again just importing the other workbooks once.

Comment: Without delving too deeply into the structure, this looks like a job for PowerQuery. Or use s/sheet functions with links to the source files.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Kevin, opening file from UDF will drain your memory. One option, of course, is to work on the file handling. However, I'd like to suggest another solution. See if it helps:

To make sure I understand you correctly:

- Combined.xlsx - List of part numbers (column E) with some kind of grouping (column H)
- BufferDays.xlsx - Possibly buffer days (column B) for the part numbers (Column A). One part number could have multiple buffer days.

You want to select a group (`cellValue`) of part numbers from Combined.xlsx, get all buffer day entries in BufferDays.xlsx with the part numbers belongs to the selected group. And identify the Max buffer day.

You can achieve this using a single array formula as follows:

```
=MAX(
     NOT(
         ISERROR(
                 MATCH(cellValue & ["part number" range in BufferDays.xls],["group" range in Combined.xls] & ["part number range in Combined.xls],0)
         )
     )*["buffer days" range in BufferDays.xls]
 )
```

In brief, the `ISERROR(Match())` part was trying to match `[cellValue][partNumber]` in BufferDays.xls, with `[group][partNumber]` in Combined.xlsx, and return an array of True/False (i.e.to determine the buffer days need to be considered in `MAX()`.  And then `Max()` just return the largest buffer days

Some points to note:

1. use exact range in the formula instead of "A:A", "H:H", etc. Otherwise, it would take forever to run
2. to make the formula simpler and/or make the two files more "scalable", you may consider to change them into tables in Excel. Then you don't need to worry about the number of entries in the tables, and your formula would be easier to understand
3. this is an array formula. Be reminded to use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after inputting the formula.
4. As DS_London pointed out, this could better be a job by PowerQuery, (or connecting multiple tables using Power Pivot)