# Excel VBA assign value to named range from user defined function fails error 1004

Tags: excel, range, named, vba

I have a function in a module. The function is defined as follows:

```
Public Function CourseSetup(ByVal SROfferId As Integer) as string
```

When the function called, The following line fails:

```
Worksheets("CourseEvaluation").Range("CourseName").value = "1234"
```

fails with error 1004.

The same line in a sub (macro) works. `CourseName` is a one cell named ranged. Getting the value for the above range works.

In the immediate window:

```
?Worksheets("CourseEvaluation").Range("CourseName").value
```

returns the current value in the range.

Comment: Are you calling this function from the worksheet formula?

Comment: Yes, by entering =CourseSetup(+srof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions called from the worksheet *cannot* manipulate worksheet objects other than the active cell wherein the formula is entered.

This preserves dependencies in formulae, prevents circular reference errors, etc.

**As a general rule**, use Subroutines to manipulate objects, and use Formulae to return values (whether to a cell reference or to a variable).

One exception is that a UDF called from *within* a subroutine *can* manipulate worksheet objects, but this is probably not a good habit to start.  Keep your functions limited to returning values to variables/cells, and use subroutines to manipulate objects.

**Further reading:**

[Making Excel functions affect 'other' cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201261/making-excel-functions-affect-other-cells)

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/477157-changing-cell-values-from-within-udf.html

http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson21.htm

Comment: This was the behavior I saw but needed your confirmation! It does make sense from a security stand point Thank you

Answer (score 2):

user defined functions called from cells can only return values to the cell(s) they are called from. So your UDF is not allowed to write values to a defined name.

Comment: This was the behavior I saw but needed the confirmation. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem a few days ago and found this answer. converting to a sub from a function solved the problem. However, if I called the function in the immediate window, it performed as desired. thought that was odd.