# Excel VBA: Call Sub procedure after executing a function

Tags: vba, excel

In myFunction, I want to create a log in a sheet with the arguments of the function and the time it was last executed.

My code is like this:

```
Function myFunction(arg1, arg2 As String)

   //code here

   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = arg1
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = arg2
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = datetime.Now

End Function
```

This function doesn't work with the last 3 lines (it does otherwise).

I also tried to create a separate module for this task:

```
Function myFunction(arg1, arg2 As String)

       //code here

    Call myLog(arg1,arg2)

    End Function
```

But it doesn't work either

```
Public Sub myLog(arg1,arg2)
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = arg1
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = arg2
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = datetime.Now
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: take a look here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/617567-calling-another-sub-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: @Mark both arguments of the function are declared as Public

Comment: Does the code give you an actual error, or does it run, but not fill in the cells?

Comment: @Blackhawk it doesn't run. It just returns #VALUE! error when I type the function in a cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It just returns #VALUE! error when **I type the function in a cell**".

A function can only modify the cell which it is called from. So you will get an error when you try to modify other cells.

Here are some references that might be useful:

[Making Excel functions affect 'other' cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201261/making-excel-functions-affect-other-cells)

[VBA - Update Other Cells via User-Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501759/vba-update-other-cells-via-user-defined-function)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?508759-Counting-Particular-Letter-Occurrences-in-a-String

Comment: Considering all the dependencies of the UDF (it might affect several other cells that depend on it) it doesn't seem to make sense to do this. Perhaps pushing the data to an array would work better (consume less resources). Thanks for your answer