# Add Hyperlink in VBA UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen how to edit a hyperlink - but I need to add a hyperlink when used as a custom formula.

I get a *#VALUE* error and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any ideas why I get a *#VALUE* error when I try to use it in a sheet as `=testit39()`

```
Public Function testit39() As String
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As range, milestoneinfo As String, milestonesymbol As String

Set rng = Application.Caller
milestoneinfo = "info"
milestonesymbol = "symbol"
If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    rng.Hyperlinks(1).address = ""
    rng.Hyperlinks(1).screentip = milestoneinfo
    Else
   ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, _
                               address:="", _
                               screentip:=milestoneinfo

    rng.Hyperlinks(1).screentip = milestoneinfo
    End If

 testit39 = milestonesymbol
 End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way that is not complicated thanks to this wonderful tutorial..

http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html

So essentially you put it in a hyperlink and you're free to do as you please..

```
=hyperlink(testit39(), "Wahoo it works!")
```

Answer (score 1):

UDFs (User-defined functions) are only allowed to return a value, they may not e.g. [affect other cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201261/making-excel-functions-affect-other-cells) or do other manipulations.
When you single-step through your code, you'll see that it aborts on the `...Hyperlinks.Add`-line (and returns an error value).

Comment: it is actually possibly but requires complex workarounds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change

Comment: Not complex if you use the hyperlink function.. http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html

Answer (score 0):

Following VBA Sub code snippet allows adding new Hyperlink, or editing existing in a specified sample cell "A1" (non-essential part of your code has been removed for better clarity):

```
Public Sub AddOrEditHyperlink(milestonesymbol As String)
    Dim rng As Range, milestoneinfo As String
    'test range
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    'sample properties
    milestoneinfo = "info"
    'if Hyperlink exists, display "Edited"
    If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address = ""
        rng.Hyperlinks(1).ScreenTip = milestoneinfo
        rng.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = "Edited Hyperlink"
    Else 'if Hyperlink does not exist, add and display "New"
        rng.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=rng, _
        Address:="", _
        ScreenTip:=milestoneinfo, _
        TextToDisplay:="New Hyperlink"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can call this Sub from the Function that you can define (UDF) corresponding to the rest of business logic of your project (which is a bit unclear articulated):

```
Public Function testit39() As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim rng As Range, milestoneinfo As String, milestonesymbol As String
    Call AddOrEditHyperlink("some Symbol")
    testit39 = milestonesymbol
End Function
```

Hope this will help. Best regards