# Excel VBA for rendering a hyperlink in a cell

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I would like to write my own macro / function in VBA for Excel that introduces a new "formula" `JIRA(ISSUE_ID)` in Excel so that I can use

```
=JIRA("ISSUE_ID")
```

in a cell and it renders the following link (pseudo Markdown syntax)

```
[ISSUE_ID](http://my.jira.com/browse/ISSUE_ID)
```

in the very same cell, where `[ISSUE_ID]` is the link text to be shown in the cell and `(http://my.jira.com/tracker/ISSUE)` is the URL for the link.

Here is an example that hopefully clarifies my needs:

I use the "formula" `=JIRA("ABC-1234")` and what my VBA function should do, is rendering a hyperlink into the very same cell that holds this formula which shows **ABC-1234** as the content of the cell which is a hyperlink to `http://my.jira.com/browse/ABC-1234`.

In VBA pseudo-code, my function writes like this:

```
Function JIRA(issue_id)
    current_cell = cell_in_which_this_function_is_used_as_formula()
    url = "http://my.jira.com/browse/" + issue_id
    current_cell.content = issue_id     'text to be shown in the cell
    current_cell.hyperlink = url        'hyperlink to be used for the cell
End Function
```

I can achieve the same result with `=HYPERLINK("http://my.jira.com/browse/ISSUE", "ISSUE")` but I don't want to write this lengthy function every time. I also don't want to use 2 columns to achieve this (e.g. `=Hyperlink("http://my.jira.com/" & B1,B1)`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Hyperlink in VBA UDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585398/add-hyperlink-in-vba-udf)

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you want and need. Because I understand that you need a function that will do exactly as `HYPERLINK`, and send the same parameters... Please amplify your question.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal - thanks for your comment! I tried to simplify and clarify my question. Maybe now it's clear what I want to do.

Comment: And always is the same hyperlink? I think now I understand you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible. You could just write a subroutine to the worksheet change event to automatically add `=HYPERLINK("http://my.jira.com/TRACKER/ISSUE", "ISSUE")` where you need it whenever cells are updated in the columns holding TRACKER and ISSUE. You could simply build the formula off of the text entered into the cells.

Or, you could do this:

```
=Hyperlink("http://my.jira.com/" & A1 & "/" & B1,B1)
```

Assuming that your Tracker column is in column A and your Issue column is in column B. Drag and drop the formula and it will self adjust.

Comment: I clarified my question and I hope now it's clear why I won't accept this as a solution.

Comment: Then you would need to build that functionality into the worksheet change event. There are workarounds for what you want, but there is no simple way to do what you're looking to do without going through the worksheet change event. Others have posted code for this, so I won't.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way. In ThisWorkbook:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Dim cell As Range
        Set cell = Target.Cells(1, 1)
        If LCase(Left(cell.formula, 5)) = "=jira" Then
            If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                cell.Hyperlinks.Delete
            End If
            Dim issue As String
            issue = Evaluate(cell.formula)
            cell.Hyperlinks.Add cell, _
                                "http://my.jira.com/browse/" & issue, _
                                issue, _
                                "Click to view issue " & issue
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

and in a module

```
Public Function Jira(id As String)
    Jira = id
End Function
```

[image: JIRA in action]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can just put the value `Issue001` (or whatever the issue is) inside the cell and run this code

```
Sub setTheHyperLink()
    Dim lastPart
    Dim theScreenTip
    Dim i
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim theLink

    Set rngList = Selection 'set the range where you have the "Issue"

For Each i In rngList
    lastPart = i.Value
    theScreenTip = lastPart
    theLink = "http://my.jira.com/TRACKER/" & theScreenTip

    If i.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        i.Hyperlinks(1).Address = theLink
        i.Hyperlinks(1).ScreenTip = theScreenTip
        i.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = theScreenTip
    Else
        i.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=i, _
        Address:=theLink, _
        ScreenTip:=theScreenTip, _
        TextToDisplay:=theScreenTip
    End If
Next i
```

With that cell defined, you don't need the UDF with this.