# How to pass the "If" result to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm creating a business trip cost table with the following columns:
`"A" = Status` ; `"B" = planned costs` (other columns doesn't matter now)
Column "A" has drop down list with "planned, done, cancelled" values.
Column "B" cells always has a number in it. (So in B column I can't write any function, because It will overwrite the price).

What I want is a criteria or code when the status in column "A" is changed to "cancelled", then the planned cost next to it becomes 0 or clears the cell.

I started to do this with a support sheet where I wrote a simple IF statement like this (in sheet2 random cell) `=if(A2="cancelled"; B2=0; "")`. But in this way it doesn't working. Simply gives a false result in to the random cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can't type to column B, I don't think you will be able to overwrite it without VB. What you can do is, to add an extra column, and do something like `=IF($A2="cancelled"; B2*0; B2)` to show the updated costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you asked for using just formulas in some other cells:

[Making Excel functions affect 'other' cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201261/making-excel-functions-affect-other-cells)

'=if(A2="cancelled"; B2=0; "")' Simply returns a logical value for "question" if B2 is equal to 0 if A2 happens to be cancelled. This is not what you want.

You could create a VBA code that would be executed each time something changes in your sheet.

[automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

Press Alt+F11 then double click on the sheet you want the functionality and add the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value = "cancelled" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = 0
End If

End Sub
```

But I would strongly advise against using this solution, because now you would simply be overwriting whatever you have in cell in column B with value 0. Therefore you would lose your previous data in this cell.

What I would do:

1) If the data in column B is fed from somewhere else (not manually written) then I would write the function there, i.e. "=if(A2="cancelled";0; .get_original_value)"

2) If the input is manual I would add another column to keep "real value" there that would work like the function from point 1)

3) Or instead of 2) you can change only the display of the cells in column B based on values in column A by using conditional formatting
You can start reading for example here
http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html
Most likely you calculate some aggregates (like sums) and want the cancelled value to be 0 for the sake of this calculations. By changing  just the display the value would remain non-zero so instead of regular SUM you would have to use SUMIF and exclude the cancelled values, for example =SUMIF(A:A;"<>cancelled";B:B).

Answer (score 0):

`=if(A2="cancelled"; B2=0; "")`: couple of things

You are using semicolons instead of commas
also you dont need to explicitly state `B2 = 0` if this formula is going into the B column

Comment: Semicolons and commas are defined by the client's regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

As already said: you cant change the cell without VBA. You would need something like this in the code-pane of the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.Value = "cancelled" Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Or do it (as also said before) in the "helper column" way with a formula like this:

```
=$B2*($A2<>"cancelled")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(A2="cancelled",0,B2)
```

put this formula in C2 and C2 will display the result as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third column(perhabs hidden) which hold the value now present in "B". Then use the function `=IF(A2="cancelled";0;C2)`in column "B".